# Number of bytes written is always -1

Tags: c, arrays, pipe, byte, fwrite

I'm trying to implement some IPC without mutex's,conditions and semaphores, only using pipes.
The following code represents a parent process forking in 3 childs (p11,p12,p13)
the parent wakes up all the childs with a `SIGUSR2` signal,then p11 starts writing 50 random numbers to the pipe. p12 and p13 competitively read from the pipe and write the numbers they get to their own file (file12 and file13). The 50th number is a `-1`, once the childs read -1, they exit.
The `write` used in the p11 child, just doesn't write a single byte, it returns `-1`
I can only use `write(2)` and `read(2)` calls for writing and reading.
I can't seem to be able to implement it, I tried several times with no results. Hope you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void handler(int signo)
{
    printf("\nSignal intercepted!\n");
}

void main ()
{
srand(time(NULL));
signal(SIGUSR2,handler);
int pa[2];
pipe(pa[2]); //create pipe
pid_t pid1,pid2,pid3;
if((pid1=fork())==0)  //child 11
    {
        close(pa[0]); //close the read side of the pipe
        pause();
        int i,nwrite,num;
        for(i=0;i<49;i++)
            {

            num=rand()%100+1; //generate a random number
            nwrite=write(pa[1],&num,sizeof(int)); //write it to the  pipe
            if(nwrite==-1) //if there's a write error
                {
                printf("\nWrite error..\n");
                exit(-1);
                }
            }
        num=-1; //generate the last number
        nwrite=(write(pa[1],&num,sizeof(int))); //write the last number to the pipe
        if (nwrite==-1) //if there's a write error
            {
            printf("\nError,now exiting...\n");
            exit(-1);
            }   
        close(pa[1]); //close the pipe in write mode
        exit(1); 
    }

else if ((pid2=fork())==0) //child 12
    {

    close(pa[1]); //close the write side of the pipe
    pause();
    int fd1,nread,num;
    fd1=open("file12.txt",O_CREAT,0777); //create a new file
    while((nread=read(pa[0],&num,sizeof(num)))>0)  //while there are bytes to read
        {
            if(num!=-1) //if this isn't the last number
                {
            write(fd1,&num,sizeof(num)); //write it to the file
                }
            else
                {   
                printf("\n-1 sent!\n"); //notify the last read number
                close(pa[0]); //close the read side of the pipe
                    close(fd1); //close the file descriptor
                    exit(1); //exit
                    }
            }   
        }



    else if ((pid3=fork())==0) //child 13, same as 12
        {
            close(pa[1]);   
            pause();
            int fd2,nread,num;
            fd2=open("file13.txt",O_CREAT,0777);

            while((nread=read(pa[0],&num,sizeof(num)))>0)
                {
                    if(num!=-1)
                    {
                            write(fd2,&num,sizeof(num));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("\n-1 sent!\n");
                        close(pa[0]);
                        close(fd2);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }   
        }




else //parent
    {   
        sleep(1);
        kill(pid1,SIGUSR2); //wake up all the childs
        kill(pid2,SIGUSR2);
        kill(pid3,SIGUSR2);
        waitpid(pid1,0,NULL); //wait for the childs to end
        waitpid(pid2,0,NULL);
        waitpid(pid3,0,NULL);
        printf("\nDone, now exiting...\n"); //exit
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler yell out in pain on this: `pipe(pa[2]);`?

Comment: Also to receive more detailed info in case of failing functions replace this things like this `printf("\nWrite error..\n");` by `perror("write() failed");`

Comment: Also^2 : Thou shalt not printf from signal-handlers.

Comment: Also^3: Add error checking to ***all*** relevant function calls. "relevant" are to be considered those which could fail and by doing so influence the program's logical flow. This just not make your program safer, but also is debugging for free.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast answers. I already checked some of those relevant functions, that's why I didn't check them in this piece of code. But yeah, you are right, I should do that. Why shouldn't I printf in signal handlers? To avoid buffer errors?

Comment: In signal handler one should only use functions which are guaranteed to by async-signal-safe. `printf()` isn't. Read on here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04 to find a list of functions one may use from out of signal handlers.

Comment: Thank you for the precious info. It's always good to learn new things.

Comment: when any parameter to a function is not used (like the `signo` parameter), then the first line in the function body needs to be: `(void)signo;`    When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Amongst MANY other problems, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  1) `int main( void )` 2) `int main( int, char ** )`  I.E. the return type from `main()` is always an `int`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code, indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}',  Never use tabs for indenting.  2) use consistent horizontal and vertical spacing.  For vertical spacing: for each code block (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) should be separated via a blank line (not some random number (including 0) of blank lines

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three kinds of return values: <0 when an error occurred, ==0 when executing the child process,  >0 when executing the parent process.   The posted code is not handling the error condition

Comment: the `time()` function returns a `time_t` however the `srand()` function is expecting a `unsigned int` parameter,  to avoid a compiler warnings, cast the returned value from `time()` to `unsigned int`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std-gnu99` )

Comment: the function: `write()` returns an `ssize_t`, not an `int`.   The `read()` function returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: Please read the man page for system functions that the code uses.  The third parameter to `waitpid()` is and `int`, not a pointer, so the third parameter should be 0 not NULL.

Comment: regarding this (and similar lines) `nwrite=(write(pa[1],&num,sizeof(int)));`  the extra set of parens just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest removing the outer set of parens.

Comment: when calling system functions (like `open()`), always check the returned value to assure the function was successful, before using the results of that function call.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this<sup>*1</sup>

```
int pa[2];
pipe(pa[2]);
```

should be

```
int pa[2];
pipe(pa);
```

Background:

`pa[2]` evaluates to `int`. `pipe()` on the other hand expects a `int[2]`, which in the context of defining a function's parameter is the same as `int[]` which is the same as  `int *`.

If an array gets passed to a function it decays to a pointer its 1st element. So passing `pa` to `pipe()` would result in passing `&pa[0]`, which indeed is an `int *`.

---

<sup>*1</sup>
*BTW, coding `pa[2]` provokes undefined behaviour in any case as it reads out the **3rd** element of `pa`, with `pa` only having two elements.*

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a distraction error, damn. I was going crazy on this. Any Idea about why, after the fix to the `pipe(pa)` line, the childs still don't write a thing to the files?

Comment: @GiulioPaoli: Adjust and complete the code's error handling and logging as proposed by my comments to your question and get enlightened ... ;-)

Comment: @GiulioPaoli: Also take compiler warnings serious and fix the code until they are gone.

Comment: Oook, I will. Thank you, again.

Comment: Hey, just for saying, I solve this! thank you. After checking every relevant function in my code, I found that the write to the file was failing due to bad opening of the fail. I was calling `open` with the `O_CREAT` flag, but without the `O_RDWR` one! That didn't open the file in read-write mode and that's why it wasn't working. Thank you again. This tip will make me save so much time!

Comment: Glad it helped. Also you can very well add an answer to your own question. And even accept it then.

Comment: Well, yours was the best, so yours is the accepted!